# What happens if you dereference `new int`?

Tags: c++, initialization, undefined-behavior

Is the following safe?

```
*(new int);
```

I get output as `0`.

Comment: Why on earth would you do that? You `new` an object, but don't assign it to a pointer, so now it is reserved but you lost the address. You just immediately leaked that object.

Comment: The code as shown is technically correct, though pointless and leaking. Attempting to actually do something with the resulting `int` - e.g. printing it - is technically undefined behavior, since the `int` is uninitialized. If you reliably get `0`, it's only by accident.

Comment: @Cyber what if I do `delete &(*(new int));`? no more leak.

Comment: Well, yes, no more leak - but what's the point? It's just an elaborate (almost) no-op.

Comment: @Deduplicator: it's undefined behavior because the standard says so. What you appear to be trying to say is that, on modern systems, this UB is unlikely to manifest as, say, a crash. "Seems to work" is one possible manifestation of undefined behavior.

Comment: @Deduplicator: why does it matter what kind of memory it is? Accessing an object before it's initialized exhibits undefined behavior. Which part of the standard, do you believe, distinguish between "modern systems" and other kinds of systems, and prescribes different behavior for them?

Comment: @Deduplicator: Igor is right. It doesn't matter how the implementation handles the UB; it's still UB.

Answer (score 12):

It’s undefined because you’re reading an object with an indeterminate value. The expression `new int()` uses zero-initialisation, guaranteeing a zero value, while `new int` (without parentheses) uses default-initialisation, giving you an indeterminate value. This is effectively the same as saying:

```
int x;              // not initialised
cout << x << '\n';  // undefined value
```

But in addition, since you are immediately dereferencing the pointer to the object you just allocated, and do not store the pointer anywhere, this constitutes a memory leak.

Note that the presence of such an expression does not necessarily make a program ill-formed; this is a perfectly valid program, because it sets the value of the object before reading it:

```
int& x = *(new int);  // x is an alias for a nameless new int of undefined value
x = 42;
cout << x << '\n';
delete &x;
```

Answer (score 8):

This is [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)(*UB*) since you are accessing an indeterminate value, C++14 clearly makes this undefined behavior. We can see that `new` without initializer is *default initialized*, from the [draft C++14 standard](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/blob/b7b8ed08ba4c111ad03e13e8524a1b746cb74ec6/papers/N3936.pdf) section `5.3.4` *New* paragraph *17* which says (*emphasis mine going forward*):

> If the new-initializer is omitted, the object is default-initialized
>   (8.5). [ Note: If no initialization is performed, the object has an
>   indeterminate value. —end note ]

for *int* this means an indeterminate value, from section `8.5` paragraph *7* which says:

> To default-initialize an object of type T means:
>
> — if T is a (possibly cv-qualified) class type (Clause 9), the default constructor (12.1) for T is called (and
>   the initialization is ill-formed if T has no default constructor or overload resolution (13.3) results in an
>   ambiguity or in a function that is deleted or inaccessible from the context of the initialization);
>
> —   if T is an array type, each element is default-initialized;
>
> —   **otherwise, no initialization is performed.**

we can see from section `8.5` that producing an indeterminate value is undefined:

> If no initializer is specified for an object, the object is
>   **default-initialized**. When storage for an object with automatic or
>   dynamic storage duration is obtained, **the object has an indeterminate
>   value**, and if no initialization is performed for the object, that
>   object retains an indeterminate value until that value is replaced
>   (5.17). [ Note: Objects with static or thread storage duration are
>   zero-initialized, see 3.6.2. — end note
>   **If an indeterminate value is produced by an evaluation, the behavior is undefined except in the following cases**

and all the exceptions have to do with *unsigned narrow char* which *int* is not.

Jon brings up an interesting example:

```
int& x = *(new int);
```

it may not be immediately obvious why this is not undefined behavior. The key point to notice is that is is undefined behavior to produce a *value* but in this case no value is produced. We can see this by going to section `8.5.3` *References*, which covers initialization of references and it says:

> A reference to type “cv1 T1” is initialized by an expression of type “cv2 T2” as follows:
>
> > — If the reference is an lvalue reference and the initializer expression
> >
> > > — is an lvalue (but is not a bit-field), and “cv1 T1” is reference-compatible with “cv2 T2,” or

and goes on to say:

> then the reference is bound to the initializer expression lvalue in
>   the first case [...][ Note: **The usual lvalue-to-rvalue (4.1),
>   array-to-pointer (4.2), and function-to-pointer (4.3) standard
>   conversions are not needed, and therefore are suppressed,** when such
>   direct bindings to lvalues are done. —end note ]

Comment: Thanks for the rigorous answer. Regarding the last case `int& x = *(new int);`, do you mean that there are no rvalues at all and both LHS and RHS are lvalues? And, you mean that the "lvalue-to-rvalue" conversion is not needed here?

Also, I wonder what would happen if it's not `int`, but some class with default initialization. Will there be no UB and just leak?

Answer (score 2):

It is possible that a computer has "trapping" values of `int`: invalid values, such as a checksum bit which raises a hardware exception when it doesn't match its expected state.

In general, uninitialized values lead to undefined behavior. Initialize it first.

Otherwise, no, there's nothing wrong or really unusual about dereferencing a new-expression. Here is some odd, but entirely valid code using your construction:

```
int & ir = * ( new int ) = 0;
…
delete & ir;
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, *Shafik Yaghmour* gave references to the Standard in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25395408/1543378). That is the best, complete and authoritative answer. None the less, let me try to give you specific examples that should illustrate the aforementioned points.

This code is safe, well-formed and meaningful:

```
int *p = new int;       // ie this is a local variable (ptr) that points 
                        // to a heap-allocated block
```

You must not, however, dereference the pointer as that results in **undefined behavior**. IE you may get 0x00, or 0xFFFFFFFF, or the instruction pointer (aka RIP register on Intel) may jump to a random location. The computer may crash.

```
int *p = new int;
std::cout << *p;    // Very, bad. Undefined behavior.
```

Run-time checkers such as [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) and [ASan](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AddressSanitizer.html) will catch the issue, flag it and crash with a nice error message.

It is, however, perfectly fine to initialize the memory block you had allocated:

```
int *p = new int;
*p = 0;
```

Background info: this particular way of writing the specification is very useful for performance, as it is prohibitively expensive to implement the alternative.

Note, as per the Standard references, sometimes the initialization is cheap, so you can do the following:

```
// at the file scope
int global1;          // zero-initialized
int global2 = 1;      // explicitly initialized

void f()
{
    std::cout << global1;
}
```

These things go into the executable's sections (.bss and .data) and are initialized by the OS loader.

Comment: I can see how the location allocated on the heap might contain a "random" value, as you say, but how could dereferencing the pointer cause the Instruction Pointer to "jump to a random location"?

Comment: It does not, on current processors and compilers. But the Standard reserves the right to do so :) This case is trivial in terms of semantics and code generation... but there are many other "undefined behavior" cases where a branch depends on this value. Eg if (*p) or even p->do_something();