# C++ usage: what does " *(new int); " do?

Tags: c++

I saw a usage of the `*` operator in front of the new operator. What does it do?

```
int x= *(new int);
```

Comment: It leaks memory. Don't do it.

Comment: Also causes undefined behaviour by reading an uninitialized int

Comment: @M.M More of a garbage value than UB, unless we know how `x` is used later ;)

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35191252/what-does-this-reference-notation-signify

Comment: I hope that was in a section titled **Things You Should Not Do**.

Comment: @CinCout the code reads from the uninitialized memory allocated by `new int` , in order to initialize x, which causes UB , [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23415662/1505939)

Comment: Also see [What happens if you dereference `new int`?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25395297/1708801)

Answer (score 4):

```
new int
```

is allocating memory.

By using defering operator * you are getting the value present at that memory location which would be garbage.

```
#include <iostream>

void main()
{
    int x = *(new int);
    std::cout << x;
    system("pause");
}
```

But this will cause the memory leak.

Answer (score 1):

The expression `new int` creates an object of type `int` in allocated memory and returns a pointer to said object. Because no initializer is specified, the object is *default-initialized* and therefore has an *indeterminate value*.

The expression `int x = *(new int)` initializes `x` with the value of the object referenced by the pointer returned by `new int`. However, accessing indeterminate values in this way is *undefined behaviour*. Since standard imposes no requirements on the behaviour of programs containing undefined behaviour, any program containing the expression `int x = *(new int)` could, in theory, do *anything at all*.

If your were to initialize the object created by the `new` expression (e.g. `new int()`), then `x` would have whatever value you initialized the original object with. However, since you didn't store the pointer to the original object, there is no way to destroy the object using `delete`, so you have a *memory leak*.

Comment: Technically, it just produces a reference to the new object. E.g. consider `int &r = *(new int);`

Comment: @Hurkyl Thanks. You are right. The undefined behaviour will only be invoked when the value of `*(new int)` is evaluated. I have updated my answer, so it should be technically correct now.

Comment: @Hurkyl, in that case you are forced to use `delete &r` once you don't need the allocated object anymore.  Or you'll continue to have a memory leak.